# Regex to detect parentheses containing a weight

Tags: java, regex

I'm having difficulties with getting my regex right.

I used this link, for detecting weight:
[regex to get weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045576/regex-to-get-weight)

This was the term to only find the weight, which worked:

```
([\d.]+)\s+(lbs?|oz|g|kg)
```

I wrote a Java method to color the dosage of medicaments on a html page. It should color all the text in parentheses, if it contains at least one indication of weight. (e.g. below 18: 5.5mg, over 18: 10mg)
Currently it will sometimes color the right part, but most of the time the regex gets too much or ignores a parenthese, that should be colored.

**Problem currently:** regex also contains every word after the closing parenthese until the end of the line.

Here my current regex:

```
(\\(.[^\\(]*.\\d*\\,?\\d+)\\s?+(µg|mg|g|kg).*.\\)
```

Here the entire method:

```
private static String addDosageHighlight(String htmltext) {

    String dosage = "";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\(.[^\\(]*.\\d*\\,?\\d+)\\s?+(µg|mg|g|kg).*.\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmltext);
    // Check all occurrences
    if (matcher.find()) {
        dosage = matcher.group();
        htmltext = htmltext.replace(dosage, "<span style=\"color:magenta;\">" + dosage +"</span>"); 
    }   
    return htmltext;
}
```

**Examples:**

```
medicament b (under 18: 10 g, over 18: 15 g) works well

medicament c (sometimes 15g if needed) can help

(sometimes 10 g)
```

Those all get detected, but will color all text until the end of the line, after the parentheses. I couldn't manage to get a parentheses that won't be colored which should be good.

Comment: Format your code better. And what is `text`

Comment: You haven't shown any examples of the text you want to capture, and which cases fail and which succeed.

Comment: A common abbreviation for micrograms when the greek mu is not available is ***mcg***.  Also some dosages are in IU.

Comment: Added a few examples

Comment: Your discussion says brackets but your examples show parentheses — brackets = `[]` braces = `{}` parentheses = `()`

Comment: Thanks I am not a native speaker. Changed it to parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify if you accept decimals, but from your regex, I assume you allow decimal numbers with a comma as decimal mark.

So, I believe that this regex will do what you are looking for:

```
"\\([^\\)]*\\d+(,\\d+)?\\s*(µg|mg|g|kg)[^\\)]*\\)"
```

Comment: Still has the same problem. Only difference is now, that if there is a second closing parenthesis it will end there.

Example:
"t(es) (etafda e 25,5 mg)  tadfasfea( afdwe) fda"

Comment: I get this output with your example: `t(es) <span style="color:magenta;">(etafda e 25,5 mg)</span> tadfasfea( afdwe) fda`. What is the expected output?

Comment: It should be "(etafda e 25,5 mg)"
I get "(etafda e 25,5 mg) tadfasfea( afdwe)"

Comment: Oh, thanks it works perfectly with copy paste. I am sorry, I thought I had to enter dots in between for it to work in java.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex, your `.*` is too greedy and wants to eat as many characters as possible. Instead you could use something like `[^)]*` which will attempt to match all characters which are not a `)` symbol.